# Primefaces nested p:dialog DOM node duplicates

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a list element detail form opening inside a `p:dialog`. This `p:dialog` in turn shows another list. From this list, I can open any of its element's details inside a nested `p:dialog`.

The problem is: every time I open a dialog, a new set of ids for the elements in the nested dialog is generated, with the same value.

What I end up with in my DOM when I try to select a particular id from the nested dialog, such as `$('#manageIssue\\:newEventComment');`, is an **array** of elements with the same id.

[image]

I have determined there is one copy per each time I open a dialog, plus another one which is there from the beginning.

**The nested dialog DOM nodes are not being destroyed when the nested dialog is closed, and a fresh set with overlapping ids is being generated every time a dialog is opened**.

This question is related to [primefaces update attribute not working on modal dialog opened from modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33391653/1060686).

(I solved the original problem by removing the `prependId` attribute from the form, but this one remained.)

Because this problem is a little difficult to reproduce, I have built a MCVE. All the stuff (backing beans, views, pom.xml, etc.) adds up to ~500 lines of code, so I have shared it on a github repo: https://github.com/elcodedocle/testt

The question here boils down to:

How can I make this MCVE work (i.e. add events with comments to an issue from a list of issues of a commission from a list of commissions), without this line:

https://github.com/elcodedocle/testt/blob/fbfeb7fca474c66c202c92e469ca185c6bf569c2/src/main/webapp/views/widgets/issue_detail_edit.xhtml#L21

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is caused by nested `<p:dialog>`.

```
<p:dialog id="commissionDetail">
    ...
    <p:dialog id="issueDetail">
        ...
    </p:dialog>
</p:dialog>
```

This is not allowed. The technical reason is, the HTML DOM element representing the dialog is by JavaScript relocated to the very end of `<body>` in order to ensure best cross browser compatibility as to calculating the z-index and offset. Then, when you ajax-update the dialog, the existing dialog couldn't be found in its original parent element in the DOM, so simply a new one is added to DOM (which then get relocated to end of body again, etc).

You really need to restructure your templates so you ultimately end up like

```
<p:dialog id="commissionDetail">
    ...
</p:dialog>
<p:dialog id="issueDetail">
    ...
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Awesome! That solved the issue. Thank you so much :-)